# Change colors of part of y axis ticks in heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a heatmap:

```
heatmap <- ggplot(df, aes(ID, Name)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = N))
```

I want to change colors of y ticks in heatmap, if they are equal to 300, 301, 302. How could in do that? Its unclear to me how to do that for part of ticks. For all, i add

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y = element_text(colour="red"))
```

but how just for 300, 301, 302?

Answer (score 1):

You need a vector of colors in `element_text` with the same number of elements as you have ticks.  I'll change the 3rd element of the x axis ("C") green as a demo:

```
x <- LETTERS[1:5]
y <- paste0("var", seq(1,5))
data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
data$Z <- runif(25, 0, 5)

ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill= Z)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="blue") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = c('black', 'black','green', 'black', 'black')))
```

[image]

Note: `ggplot` doesn't love vectorized input to `element_text` and will post a warning saying as such.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of single color you've to use a vector of color in axis.text.y

```
library(ggplot2)

# using mtcars data
df <- data.frame(Name = 300:331,
                 ID = 1:nrow(mtcars),
                 N = mtcars$mpg)
# for df id 300, 301, 302
# first make a vector of black color
tick_colors <- rep("black", length(df$Name))
# change colors matching Name to red
tick_colors[df$Name %in% c(300, 301, 302)] <- "red"
heatmap <- ggplot(df, aes(ID, Name)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = N))
heatmap + scale_y_continuous(breaks = df$Name) + theme(
  axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
  axis.text.y = element_text(colour = tick_colors)
)
```

Output:
[Axis text color changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zASUx.png)

Comment: i get Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: You're welcome. Change this line "scale_y_continuous" to "scale_y_discrete". In ggplot depending on the values of the x and y axis you've to use either continuous or discrete after the scale_*_ .